# Recyclerview MySql int shows 0

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

so I have seen problems about data not showing on recyclerview, but non works with mine. I get data from Mysql using PHP, the php gets date and integer as Json. but when I call recyclerview the data does not show. 
PHP script, I have tested the script and it does gets the data as Json

recyclerView activity

```
public class recycle_view_sales_report extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
private String string_url = "http://10.0.3.2/sales_report.php";
private salesAdapter adapter;
Context context = this;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recycle_view_sales_report);

    this.setTitle("Customer table");
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerv);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    getinformation();
}

private void getinformation(){
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,string_url,
            new Response.Listener<String>(){

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
                    Gson gson = builder.create();


                    List<salesData> list = Arrays.asList(gson.fromJson(response,salesData[].class));
                    adapter = new salesAdapter(list,context);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener(){

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });

    MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQue(stringRequest);
}
}
```

Adapter class

```
public class salesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<salesAdapter.MyViewholder> {



private List<salesData> list = new ArrayList<>();
Context context;


salesAdapter(List<salesData> list, Context ctx){
    this.list = list;
    context = ctx;
}


@Override
public salesAdapter.MyViewholder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.sales_report_layout,parent,false);
    return new salesAdapter.MyViewholder(view,context,list);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(salesAdapter.MyViewholder holder, int position) {

    holder.datetx.setText(String.valueOf(list.get(position).getDate()));
    holder.salestx.setText(String.valueOf(list.get(position).getSales()));


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

public static class MyViewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView datetx,salestx;
    List<salesData> datas = new ArrayList<salesData>();
    Context context;

    public MyViewholder(View itemView, Context ctx, List<salesData> datas){
        super(itemView);
        this.datas = datas;
        context = ctx;

        datetx = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tx_date);
        salestx = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tx_sales);





    }}
     }
```

data class

```
  public class salesData {


 String date;
int sales;

public salesData(String date, int sales) {
    this.date = date;
    this.sales = sales;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public int getSales() {
    return sales;
}

public void setSales(int sales) {
    this.sales = sales;
}
}
```

XML RECYCLERVIEW

```
  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="120dp">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:id = "@+id/tx_id"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="Date:"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
    />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/tx_date"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="120dp"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tx_id"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tx_id"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="tx_date"
android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sales"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tx_date"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tx_date"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Sales:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tx_sales"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/sales"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sales"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="tx_sales"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"/>
```

`

XML layout

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res    /android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="120dp">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:id = "@+id/tx_id"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="Date:"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
    />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/tx_date"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="120dp"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tx_id"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tx_id"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="tx_date"
android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sales"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tx_date"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tx_date"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Sales:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"/>

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tx_sales"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/sales"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sales"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="tx_sales"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

php script

```
    <?PHP


     require "conn.php";




   $sql_qry = " SELECT calendar.datefield AS DATE, SUM(orders.price) AS      total_sales FROM orders 
   RIGHT JOIN calendar ON (DATE(orders.date_time) = calendar.datefield) GROUP BY DATE;";

  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_qry);

  $response = array();

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

  array_push($response,array("DATE"=>$row[0],"total_sales"=>$row[1]));



 }

 echo  json_encode($response);



  ?>
```

Comment: check if the JSON is being parse correctly
`List<salesData> list = Arrays.asList(gson.fromJson(response,salesData[].class));`
Set a break point to debug or print the length in LogCat

Comment: Also, the recycler view layout is not optimal if the text is long things will be truncated.

Comment: You have used volley right

Comment: can you show me the json format in php script?

Comment: @AdityaSharat In have tried that, I get the correct length, for the size the first, part should be date '2017-11-22' and second is total number around 3 to 4 digits, what is considered long,

Comment: @EnamulHaque yes I have used vollet, I added php script,

Answer (score 0):

You can try

1. My Json Look like

   {"saleNodes":[{"id":"1","saledate":"2017-10-10"}]}
2. My Php code for making json is like..

   ```
   if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

   $userDetails = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

     //  $response["id"] = $row["id"];
      $userData[] = array(
         "id" => $row["id"],
         "saledate" => $row["date"],
       );

    }

     } else {
      echo "0 results";
    }

       $result1['saleNodes'] = $userData;
       $json = json_encode($result1);
      echo $json;
   ```
3. In android application can get data

   ```
      private void getData() {
         String url="http://1.11.201.179/Airport/tour_places.php";


             StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
           new Response.Listener<String>() {
               @Override
               public void onResponse(String response) {
                   //pDialog.dismiss();


                   try {
                       JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                       JSONArray loginNodes = jsonObject.getJSONArray("saleNodes");

                       Log.e("****ddd",loginNodes.toString());
                       for (int i = 0; i < loginNodes.length(); i++) {
                           JSONObject jo = loginNodes.getJSONObject(i);
                           String name = jo.getString("saledate");

                           SalesData d = new SalesData();
                           d.setDate(name);
                           salesDatasList.add(d);

                       }
                       showCardList();


                   } catch (JSONException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }


               }
           },
           new Response.ErrorListener() {
               @Override
               public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                   //pDialog.dismiss();
                   Log.e("****ddd",error.toString());
               }
           }) {
       @Override
       protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
           Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
         //Parmeter
           return params;
       }

   };


       RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
     }
   ```
4. Adapter will look like

   ```
      //Being adapter
     void showCardList(){
       recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);


          recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(Your activity.this));


       // create an Object for Adapter
          mAdapter = new CardViewDataAdapter(salesDatasList);

        // set the adapter object to the Recyclerview
         recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
       }

          class CardViewDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardViewDataAdapter.ViewHolder> {



                public CardViewDataAdapter(ArrayList<SalesData> os_versions) {

             dataSet = os_versions;
          }


     @Override
        public CardViewDataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        // create a new view
          View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(
               R.layout.row_sale, null);


       itemLayoutView.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RecyclerView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            CardViewDataAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder = new CardViewDataAdapter.ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);

          return viewHolder;
       }

      @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(CardViewDataAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

            SalesData fp = dataSet.get(i);


           viewHolder.tv_date.setText(fp.getDate());




             viewHolder.menu = fp;
       }

       @Override
        public int getItemCount() {

         return dataSet.size();
        }

         public void updateList(List<SalesData> temp) {
             dataSet = (ArrayList<SalesData>) temp;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
          }

         // inner class to hold a reference to each item of RecyclerView
      public  class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


          public TextView tv_date;



             public SalesData menu;

           public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
               super(itemLayoutView);
               tv_date = (TextView) itemLayoutView  .findViewById(R.id.tv_date);





              }

           }
         }
     //end Adapter
   ```
5. In Activity declare the variable

   ```
     ArrayList<SalesData> salesDatasList = new ArrayList<>();
     private CardViewDataAdapter mAdapter;
    private ArrayList<SalesData> dataSet;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
   ```
6. Your mainactity.xml

   ```
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
              android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_margin="10dp"
             android:scrollbars="vertical" />
   ```
7. row_sale.xml

   ```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#FFFFFF"
   card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true" >



   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/tv_date"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"

       android:textSize="18sp"
       android:textStyle="bold"
       android:textAllCaps="true"
       android:text="date"/>

      </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
   ```
8. Your SaleDate Class

   ```
   public class SalesData {

    private String date;

   public String getDate() {
    return date;
   ```

   }

   ```
     public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
      }
   ```

   }
9. Don't forget add gadle.xml

   ```
   compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
   compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
   compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
   ```
10. above code is working for me..enjoy it...thanks in advance..